# "no acceptable c compiler found in $PATH" while installing hydra on my windows through cygwin terminal

Tags: terminal, compiler-errors, cygwin

I found an error while trying to install hydra under Windows via Cygwin. What should I do?

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Cygwin doesn't install a compiler.  I suggest installing "gcc" from Cygwin's setup.  (You may need other packages, but start with "gcc" and add packages are needed.)